# How do I create an output file of directory folders?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat script that works to provide a list of sub-directories 1 level down.  If I run from cmd line with `>> file.txt` it writes the file correctly.  But I cannot correctly insert the code into the script to print that `file.txt`.  What is the proper syntax to print the file?  I need to use this piece of code in a larger script.

```
setlocal
set currentLevel=0
set maxLevel=%2
if not defined maxLevel set maxLevel=1
:procFolder
pushd %1 2>nul || exit /b
if %currentLevel% lss %maxLevel% (
    for /d %%F in (*) do (
        echo %%~fF
        set /a currentLevel+=1
        call :procFolder "%%F"
        set /a currentLevel-=1
        >> subdir_list.txt
    )
)
popd
```

Where can I insert the code to write that file?  What is proper syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command.

Just put `type name_of_file.txt` after you have written the file like you already said you done.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a much simpler method:

dir /a:d /b > subdir_list.txt